# spelling letter with speech recognition library python

Tags: python, speech-recognition, pocketsphinx

I have my project of warship game, and I want to use `speech-recognition` with `pocket sphinx` library. I want to use a dictionary instead of google API which is quite great because I want some special word like `A8` for example in my `10*10 grid`. My question is, how can I add the pronunciation of the numbers and write it in the dictionary?

Answer (score 1):

Look into existing dictionary cmudict-en-us.dict and select the words that you need:

```
a. EY
b. B IY
c. S IY
d. D IY
e. IY
f. EH F
g. JH IY
h. EY CH
j. JH EY
k. K EY
1 W AH N
2 T UW
```

Then write a grammar:

```
<command> = <letter> <number>
<letter> = a. | b. | c. | d. | e. | f. | j. | h. | i. | j.
<number> = one | two | three
```

Note that single-letter words are very confusable, like B and D, they are very easy to confuse even for a human. Consider using [Radio Alphabet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spelling_alphabet) instead.