# Python Speech Recognition and Usernames

Tags: python, python-3.x, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

I am currently working on a more ore less little project in Python, where I build somewhat of an voice assistant that interacts with some Gaming APIs like the Destiny2 API.

The big problem I am running into is the Recognition of the usernames (gamertags) like, for example:  **Ultra_Luck_y** which the `speech_recognition` module for python I am using clearly doesn't understand. So it just returns Ultra Lucky.

I also tried spelling it, but i automatically got put together to words.
So my question is wether there is a solution (no matter how crappy) or not and I have to go a different way about this?

Comment: What output are you getting when you try saying it?

Comment: i get Ultra Lucky

Comment: Is gametag something similar to username?

Comment: Yes it is basically the same thing

Comment: Hm, I didnt understand that at first, I thought they were some commands and you can make a mapping. This makes it much harder and yeah spelling it out is pretty much the only option. Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55758017/spelling-letter-with-speech-recognition-library-python) approach?

Comment: I will try that and post the answer in 1 or 2 days if it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Azamat Galimzhanov, i solved it with the the Radio Alphabet, but kind of edited it so the Words were a little shorter.
I simply put the references all in one json document and loaded them as a dictoniary with:

```
with open('usernames.txt') as json_file:
    alphabet = json.load(json_file)
```